# I accidentally broke my fast on Yom Kippur, now what?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, mistakes, fast-days, eating

What are you supposed to do if you inadvertently broke your fast on Yom Kippur?  Do you:

1. keep going;
2. extend it (if so, how long);
3. cancel it (if so, do you make it up a different day)?

Does it make a difference if the food or drink was actually swallowed before realizing the mistake?

Comment: @Yishai: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/5323  (not really serious though)

Answer (score 6):

Continue the fast.
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: The old version of your answer applied very nicely to the old version of the question. Now that we have a real question, we need a real answer with sources, so (for now) +1 removed. [ cc @DoubleAA ]

Comment: @Shokhet I don't know why a lack of sources was acceptable before, frankly.

Comment: Would like to see all parts of the question addressed in this answer...